# No video after "apt-get upgrade" from Ubuntu 16.04.1 and 16.04.2?

Tags: apt, nvidia, upgrade, video

There are a lot of threads about incompatibilities and "gotcha" cases that people have run in to with Ubuntu and Nvidia cards, but none like the problem I'm having here.

I have a system with 3 video cards in it; an Nvidia P600, and two GTX 1080s.  The Ubuntu installer runs fine with no issues, I can set up a software RAID, and then reboot to the OS.

**Ubuntu runs fine in CLI mode without Nvidia drivers, until I run "apt-get -y upgrade".**

Once the upgrade is finished and I reboot, I lose video, forever.  I have to SSH in to the system to look around and see what's going on, but I can't find any glaring issues or errors in the logs.

This same behavior occurs when "apt-get -y upgrade"ing from a fresh 16.04.1 or 16.04.2 install.

When doing it from 16.04.2, my `/var/log/apt/history.log` file shows this as the entry for it:

```
Start-Date: 2017-03-29  18:42:59
Commandline: apt-get -y upgrade
Requested-By: user (1000)
Upgrade: init:amd64 (1.29ubuntu3, 1.29ubuntu4), init-system-helpers:amd64 (1.29ubuntu3, 1.29ubuntu4), grub-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.8), mdadm:amd64 (3.3-2ubuntu7.1, 3.3-2ubuntu7.2), nano:amd64 (2.5.3-2ubuntu1, 2.5.3-2ubuntu2), grub2-common:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.8), resolvconf:amd64 (1.78ubuntu2, 1.78ubuntu4), grub-pc:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.8), grub-pc-bin:amd64 (2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.7, 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.8)
End-Date: 2017-03-29  18:43:16
```

Again, note that I haven't even gotten to the point of installing Nvidia drivers yet; this is purely vanilla Ubuntu, and it's killing video after upgrade.

Can anyone clue me in as to what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that my cusotmized grub.cfg file was being overwritten by the upgrade.

I had forgotten that a script was running after Ubuntu installation that was adding `set linux_gfx_mode=text` to `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so that it could actually show video on boot, and running `apt-get -y upgrade` was nuking that.

I edited `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` instead of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the change became permanent.